# Function animation with plot_surface not drawing , just giving first picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, data-visualization

I have written the following code with function animation with `plot_surface` which is not drawing, just giving the first picture

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = np.outer(np.linspace(-2, 2, 50), np.ones(50))
#print(x)
y = x.copy().T # transpose
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

def animation_frame(i):
  z = np.cos(x ** 2 + y ** 2) + np.cos(x ** (2*i) + y ** (2*i)) 
  # print (z)
  
  ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
  # return ax,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, frames=np.arange(0, 10, 1), interval=1000,  blit=False)
#plt.show()
animation
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `plt.show()` method at the end. Moreover, you should erase the previous plot with `ax.cla()` at the beginning of the `animation_frame`.

**Whole code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


x = np.outer(np.linspace(-2, 2, 50), np.ones(50))
y = x.copy().T
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')


def animation_frame(i):
    ax.cla()
    z = np.cos(x**2 + y**2) + np.cos(x**(2*i) + y**(2*i))
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap = 'viridis', edgecolor = 'none')


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func = animation_frame, frames = np.arange(0, 10, 1), interval = 250, blit = False)

plt.show()
```

[image]